# Array.splice() behaves one way on array literal and another way on array saved as const

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this will be short.

I have the following code:

```js
const foo = [1,2,3,4].splice(2, 1);
console.log("foo", foo);
// [3]

const bar = [1,2,3,4]
bar.splice(2, 1);
console.log("bar", bar);
// [1, 2, 4]
```

As you can see if you run it (in Chrome at least) foo consoles to an array with single value of  `3` where bar consoles to a three-item array with all items *but* `3`.

What accounts for this difference?

Comment: That is because `foo` is the result of `splice` not the modified array literal.

Comment: It behaves the same way: in the first case you're `console.log`'ing the result `splice` returns, in the second case you _ignore_ what it returns and `console.log` something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`splice` will do two things:

- It will remove (or add) the items from the array, given the arguments (first argument is index, second argument is number of items to remove)
- It will return the removed items as an array

It does *not* return the changed (or original) array. So

```
const foo = [1,2,3,4].splice(2, 1);
console.log("foo", foo);
```

is behaving as expected; it's removing the item at index 2 (which is `3`) and returning it as an array, so `foo` evaluates to `[3]` (an array containing the single removed item).

With

```
const bar = [1,2,3,4]
bar.splice(2, 1);
console.log("bar", bar);
```

the item at index 2 is being removed from the `bar` array, but then you proceed to log the altered `bar` array, with the `3` item removed, so the result is `[1, 2, 4]`.

Might be clearer if you assigned the result of the `splice` call to something and then logged that other variable:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]
const removedItems = arr.splice(2, 1);
console.log("arr", arr);
console.log("removedItems", removedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

the method Splice removes elements from an array and returns the result of removing elements of the array you are trying to alter for example

```
var foo = [1,2,3,4]

//logging the removed items
console.log(foo.splice(2,1));
//[3]

//but if you log the array
console.log(foo);
//[1,2,4]
//logs the mutated array without the number 3
```

In your case whats happening is that the method splice returns the removed items of the array, that would be [3], but it doesn't return the operating array, so when you log the array bar you are actually loggin the full mutated array.

You can chek this description of the method splice from MDN. Array.prototype.splice()